# Working on a Git feature branch and use(?) branch at the same time

Tags: git

I'm new to Git, and sometimes I find myself working on a feature branch(say adding library A) while also working on program B that uses it(which I call the use branch, maybe there is a better word). So what I've done in the past is have two separate branches, work on the feature branch 'til it seems like it might work, then start using the API in the use branch, merge the feature branch in and see if it works. If it doesn't work, I go back to the feature branch, fix the issue, merge and repeat. Is this the best way to do this?

My goal is to keep the feature branch separate from any implementation that uses it(though I suppose even that is up for debate). What I also thought of later is presuming I'm editing a limited number of files I could just do the 'fixing' changes in the use branch and use 'git checkout' in the feature branch to bring just the library changes back in.

What I guess I really want is to be working in a single workspace, but specify that these files belong to branch A and these files belong to branch B and be able to commit them separately. (I can imagine an implementation where you specify 2(or n) branches to combine into a pseudo branch, presuming that you don't alter the same files. Then when you change files that are in one branch you can commit just those files to that branch(and if you modify new files, you have to specify which branch this file 'belongs' to)). For all I know this may be in opposition to how Git works, but I don't know it enough to tell. :)

Thoughts?

Clarifications/Addendums:

This is a single program in one repository(though two repositories may be the solution)

There are two branches I'm currently working with

Example(not actually what I'm doing :)):
I'm writing a program to generate a random number and then write it to a file. So my main program is in its own branch(what I refer to as my 'use' branch). My main program is simply:

MyFileApi::Write("myfile", random());

where random() is some system API that already exists, but MyFileApi::Write is a new feature I'm developing(so my program is using this new feature). In my 'feature branch' I have say a header file and implementation for MyFileApi::Write. So I've written some implementation of MyFileApi::Write, but I want to test it using my new random-number-file-writer program(it would probably be best to write tests specifically for this API, but I'm being lazy and testing it in my program that uses the code). So what I've been doing is merging in my MyFileApi::Write changes into my 'use' branch, testing it, seeing it fail, going back to my feature branch, fixing the issue, merging again, repeat etc...

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble following what you are asking. I can't figure out what you mean by "feature branch", "use branch", "library A", "program B", or "API". These terms don't mean anything to me, so I can't figure out what you are saying. Can you try to rephrase it, or add specifics about the project you are working on so there is some sort of reference point?

Comment: I've tried to add some clarifications to the end, let me know if that helps!

Comment: I just want to add that you really should use test cases to thoroughly test your library before you try and link to it from your application, be it new development or expanding upon a current library. Test cases should be part of the library code base and adequately test every feature that you expose from the library. If your library works as expected, then integrating it into your program will be substantially easier, knowing that any unexpected results would be from the program, and not from the library.

Comment: Yep, I agree Will, that is the best way to do it. (Thus making some of this moot :P). I guess it ends up being weird that I care enough about making separate commits but not about writing proper dedicated tests.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing preventing you from cloning the repository twice, so you have two local workspaces, one for each branch.  If the build output from the feature branch needs to be in the use branch, you can always use symlinks (assuming you are on a Unixy OS) and .gitignore them from the use branch.

However, if these are two different programs (and it sounds like they are) then they should not be on separate branches at all -- they should either be in the same directory tree in both branches, or they should be in separate repositories altogether.  It's not considered good style to have one branch exclusively for one program and one branch exclusively for another (unless they are release branches or something special like that).

Comment: It is actually a single program(sorry for the confusion, I've attempted to clarify it in my post). And yes, I agree that having two repositories and sym-linking the build output appropriately would work. I would prefer, however, to do all the work entirely on the Git side of things, to avoid delving into the build system for a large project.

Comment: Unfortunately, Git does not have any mechanism to check out two different branches in the same working tree.  So what you ask really isn't possible.  Perhaps there is an alternate solution you could use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no git guru, but you can theoretically have as many branches as you want. What I would suggest, assuming you have library A in its own git repo and program B (which uses A) in its own git repo would be:

- create a branch (for example, "new_features") in A
- modify your code, try to compile/link, fix errors
- create a branch (use the same name to show what will be tested - "new_features") in B
- modify code in B to use the new/modified features that you added/changed in A
- compile/link/test B

You really need to have the branch in your program B if the changes you are making to library A change its exposed set of functions/variables. If all you are doing is making changes to the "background" code (that is, leave the exposed functions/vars as they are while improving algorithms, memory usage, etc in those functions), you would not necessarily need a branch for your B program.

Regardless, if you branched both projects, first go to your A library and merge your branch back into the trunk. Compile/link/fix errors. Then go to B and merge its respective branch onto the trunk of that project. Again, compile/link/fix errors.

I'm actually having to do something like this with one of the projects I'm currently developing; has a main application that makes use of various shared libraries. We use SVN, but the concepts are essentially the same.